# how to count string occurences from array in php

Tags: php, explode

I have the following code which lists down everything within a text file log onto a web page. The log contains either successful or failed login details.

```
<?php
$myFile = "logs/loginLog.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');

$theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
fclose($fh);

$Chunks = explode(",", $theData);

for($x=0; $x<=sizeof($Chunks)-1; $x++)
{
    echo $Chunks[$x];
    echo"<br>";
}
?>
```

What I've been trying to do for the past few hours is count the number of times certain words ("Successful" and "Failed") appear and I've tried many approaches but I've just been given errors, though I think I may have been using them incorrectly.

P.S. I'm a total noob with PhP

Comment: `preg_match_all()` + `count()`

Comment: @Rizier123 how would i go about using that?

Comment: You match all occurrences of the word with a regex and then count the result array.

Comment: I've tried this but couldn't get it to work @Rizier123, don't think i used it correctly. Thank you though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[substr_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) comes in handy.

Use this:

```
$text = 'stackoverflow is so overflowed with questions';
echo substr_count($text, "overflow"); // 2
```

Comment: used this method but since $Chunks is an array, used `serialize()` to convert it to string. thanks for your help :)